# how to connect java with wamp mysql server

Tags: java, jdbc, wamp

I am new java programmer, I try to setup jdbc connnectivity with wamp mysql server.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://182.73.151.36:3306/sbtsystem?user=sbtuser&password=Pm@dmin&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
```

`182.73.151.36` this is server IP address. I can't understand how to connect java with wamp mysql server

Comment: so what is happening?

Comment: What problem you are having? Where are you struck? May be you need to read some tutorial on this.

Comment: http://bhrtbaj.blogspot.in/2013/03/jdbc-connection-to-mysql-database-with.html might help

Comment: You set it up the same way you set up connectivity with any other MySQL server.

Comment: suppose this connection with locahost:3306 then program run correctly.If i can used 182.73.151.36 this address then error occured communication failed.

Comment: Go through this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/ and get back to us later if any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

First run these commands

```
ping 182.73.151.36
telnet 182.73.151.36 3306
```

**And make 182.73.151.36  mysql eligible for remote connection**

After that change your connection line and run this program

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://182.73.151.36:3306/sbtsystem","sbtuser","Pm@dmin");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download the jdbc driver files for mysql 
[(download from here)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

Comment: i add this file to lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. You need to check the network configurations. Try the following commands to see if the server is accessible.

- ping 182.73.151.36
- telnet 182.73.151.36 3306

Answer (score 0):

supposing your network configuration is correct,
I guess your mysql server on 182.73.151.36 is not configured for remote connection,